# Load assembly to new app domain and communicate with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-assembly, remoting

this is not coding question - but understaing question.
I need to load a 3rd party DLL into my Process, but in a new App domain (since i must have the ability to un-load it later on).

Most samples i see over the net are with MarshalByRefObject, But as i understand, Remoting is dead.
So i think the flow should be like this:

1. From AppDomain 1 - get the DLL path
2. From AppDomain 1 - Load the dll to a new app domain
3. This is on AppDomain 2 - On my entrance class in the loaded assembly, i will put certain attribute, then by reflection (a reflection class that must be common between both assemblies) i will locate the class and instantiate an instance, In the constructor I will open WCF Service on specific address and listen to requests.
4. From AppDomain 1- At this point, I will create WCF Client on the same address and call functions on AppDomain - 2 class.

Is this scenario valid ? or should i use the samples like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde(v=vs.100).aspx

Thanks!

Comment: This link was very helpful for me: http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect. Whilst .NET **Remoting** may be "dead" for inter-process or inter-machine communications, it is far from dead for communicating with other objects running in different AppDomains in the **same process**.

Here's a MSDN article from August 2013:

- [Architecture for Hosting Third-Party .NET Plug-Ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342875.aspx)

Also **Remoting** is used in Microsoft's **System.AddIn** namespace (or MAF) in **.NET 4.5** which allows you to host addins in different **AppDomains**.  - [Add-ins and Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would recommend you look at **System.AddIn** rather than rolling your own.

Though getting old now, the following article is quite useful if you are keen on making your own add-in system.  It's for .NET 2 but I find it is still relevant - I know my plugin systems still work:

- [Do You Trust It?  Discover Techniques for Safely Hosting Untrusted Add-Ins with the .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163701.aspx)

### AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap

> *...or should i use the samples like [AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap]*

Yes.  See above articles

### Performance

I think you will find too that single-process Remoting will out-perform WCF even over named-pipes due to overhead in the latter.